# How can I get the value of <select> when checkbox is being selected in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to get the value of `<select>` if the checkbox is being selected in a row. Please see image below.

[image]

So if I triggered the submit button how can I get the values from the `<select>`? Is it possible in pure php or do I need to use javascript/jquery? If so how? Here is my markup:

```
<form method="post" action="borrow_save.php">
<table>
      <td>
        <select name="mypurpose[]">
            <option value="Overnight">Overnight</option>
            <option value="Photocopy">Photocopy</option>
            <option value="Read">Read</option>
        </select>
    </td>


    <td width="20">
        <input id="" class="uniform_on" name="selector[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" >

    </td>
</table>
</form>
```

**Edit:** I want to retrieve it the way I am retrieving the selected checkbox. Is it possible or any work arounds for that?

Comment: IDs need to be unique. You can't use the same `id="mypurpose"` for every select.

Comment: You'll need to post the `<form action="...">` tag for us to help you with the php side of this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your PHP so that you put the ID into the name of the `<select>`:

```
<select name="mypurpose[<?php echo $id; ?>]">
```

Then in your PHP, you can do:

```
foreach ($_POST['selector'] AS $selected) {
    $purpose = $_POST['mypurpose'][$selected];
    ...
}
```

Comment: So I'm going to use ajax to insert those values?

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you're looking for. When you submit it'll POST and you can grab its values from there with PHP. Throw it into a loop to grab the other ones.

```
   <form action="PurpOutput.php" method="post">
       <input type="checkbox" name="mypurpose[]" id="mypurpose" value="ThePurp">
       <input type="checkbox" name="mypurpose[]" id="mypurpose" value="Purp2">
       <input type="checkbox" name="mypurpose[]" id="mypurpose" value="Purp3">
       <input type="submit" value="submit">
   </form>
```

PurpOutput.php

```
  <?php
    $purp = $_POST['mypurpose'];
    if(isset($_POST['mypurpose'])) 
    {
     foreach ($purp as $mypurp)
     {
      echo $mypurp."<br />";
     }
    }
   ?>
```

Comment: This one will return all the `<select>` values. I just want to get the values of `<select>` wherein the checkbox is being checked in a row.

Comment: I just added onto what I said, and that should give you the values for the ones that get the checkmark in them.

Answer (score 0):

Cycle glorious master race

```
while(cycle)
    {
        $a++;
        ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="Counter" value="<? echo $a; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="a<? echo $a; ?>" value="<? echo $var; ?>"><? echo $var; ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="print<? echo $a; ?>" value="1">
}

for($z = 1; $z <= $_POST['Counter']; $z++)
{
    if(isset($_POST['print'.$z]))
    {
        echo$_POST['a'.$z];
    }
}
```